# What factors contributed to enable Rickenbacher to be found?

Tags: search-and-rescue

In Rickenbacher's autobiography he tells of his flight across the Atlantic in a B-17 after WWII. They ended up running out of gas as I recall, making a water landing in the middle of the ocean. They were stranded for about a month before being rescued.

In the early post-WWII era, how was it that they were able to find him at all? What factors contributed?

Comment: atlantic current is know to go to the west of the UK a much busier area

Answer (score 3):

[Actually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Rickenbacker#Adrift_at_sea) it was during WW2 and it was the Pacific:

> One of Rickenbacker's most famous near-death experiences occurred in October 1942 [...] The bomber strayed hundreds of miles off course while on its way to a refueling stop on Canton Island and was forced to ditch in a remote and little-traveled part of the Central Pacific Ocean.

I am not familiar with the episode, and [this source](http://www.americanheritage.com/articles/magazine/ah/2008/5/2008_5_40.shtml) is currently not working for me, but from the little information that the wiki reports, I have the impression that the main factor has been pure luck.

Comment: ah, ok, it's been a while since I read his autobiography. ;)

Comment: @flyingfisch no problem. I actually find amusing the wiki's phrasing `One of Rickenbacker's most famous near-death experiences` must have been an hell of a life

Comment: yeah it was, he got into many near-death incidents, starting at age 9 IIRC. You should read the autobiography ;)

Comment: @flyingfisch I will, thanks for bringing it up :)